# Undefined javascript function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Working on a google maps project and stuck on what seems to be a minor issue. When i call displayMarkers function firebug returns:

> ReferenceError: displayMarkers is not defined [Break On This Error]
>
> displayMarkers(1);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(25.7889689, -80.2264393);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        //var data = [[25.924292, -80.124314], [26.140795, -80.3204049], [25.7662857, -80.194692]]     var data = {"crs": {"type": "link", "properties": {"href": "http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/", "type": "proj4"}}, "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [25.924292, -80.124314]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"industry": [2], "description": "hosp", "title": "shaytac hosp2"}, "id": 35}, {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [26.140795, -80.3204049]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"industry": [1, 2], "description": "retail", "title": "shaytac retail"}, "id": 48}, {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [25.7662857, -80.194692]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"industry": [2], "description": "hosp2", "title": "shaytac hosp3"}, "id": 36}]}
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0], data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                title: console.log(data.features[i].properties.industry[0]),
                map: map
            });
            marker.category = data.features[i].properties.industry[0];
            marker.setVisible(true);
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        function displayMarkers(category) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].category === category) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    markers[i].setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Retail" onclick="displayMarkers(1);">
```

Comment: First, your code is hard to read. Second, `displayMarkers` seems to be defined inside `initialize`.

Comment: Probably you have an error before the `displayMarkers()` which is causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayMarkers` is defined inside the `initialize` function.

`onclick="displayMarkers(1);"` searches the global namespace for the function and obviously it is not there. Here is a workaround that makes `displayMarkers` function global but still able to reference variables defined inside `initialize`. Change:

```
function initialize() {
    // ...
    function displayMarkers(category) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To:

```
function initialize() {
    // ...  
    window.displayMarkers = function (category) {
        // ...  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Function `displayMarkers` must be on the global scope to be called like that (from an `onclick` attribute).

That's probably what's going on. Please format and indent your code properly, and that should be easy to spot (I think it's defined inside `initialize`, while it should be outside).

Comment: This is exactly what's going on. I just spent 10 minutes formatting it, and it's defined inside initialize.

Comment: Note: unless you make `markers` a global too, you'll have to do ehat Salman A says to keep the function working.

Comment: Moving it outside of initialize didn't make any difference in this case.

Comment: @dizpers My favorite tool for that didn't like the code, so it was just easier to do it by hand. Plus it was more like 3 minutes, but I was trying to emphasize just how bad the code's formatting was.