# Grouping Markers by Category in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I know this question has been asked before and I have looked at other Stack Overflow examples and elsewhere but have been looking at this code for too long and I am stumped still.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bato/6s9cM/), I have the markers for what will be two of many categories. I tried to set up a categories function `displayMarkers` to filter and toggle on and off the markers for each category.

I cribbed from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219437/google-maps-marker-grouping) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533110/undefined-javascript-function) with no luck.

When I try to call the `displayMarkers` function and and pass a `parameter (albacore218)`, I get `ReferenceError: albacore218 is not defined`.

Data is in JSON and works just fine to populate the data in the marker infowindows. What I don't understand is why the JSON will work in the infowindow but when I try to access the data with the categories function I have no success.

Please let me know what I am missing or am not understanding. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the string `albacore218` (and also `amberjack219`) between simple quotes. Otherwise they will be treated as variables.

```
<input type="button" value="Albacore" onclick="displayMarkers('albacore218');">
<input type="button" value="Amberjack" onclick="displayMarkers('amberjack219');">
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that! Thanks that solved the issue.